# is requestAnimationFrame needed when drawing to a hidden canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

I have code that paints to a hidden canvas `style="visibility: hidden"` and then plots this hidden canvas onto one that is visible on screen.

Now as far as I understand, with the hidden canvas drawing should be performant even if it is not triggered via `requestAnimationFrame`. Is this so? Because I would then only use `requestAnimationFrame` for the blitting of the hidden canvas on the main screen.

The app I'm working on is not heavily animated but has quite a lot of lines to draw when something changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create the canvas with `document.createElement("canvas")` and don't attach this created canvas in any DOM container instead of use a hidden style . (Needs tests to prove, but at least is another way to create a `back buffer canvas`).

Even so, in my experience I never see effective gains by using `backbuffered canvas` with `requestAnimationFrame`. In fact, requestAnimationFrame does their job of synchronize the browser paint with the monitor's refresh rate and this enables smooth animations and more responsive pages. Also the animation will stop if the user switches to another tab which saves CPU usage and battery life of mobile devices.

I would not recommend the use of a back buffer canvas and I suggest, instead, that you perform your drawing stuff directly in main canvas inside a requestAnimationFrame callback. If you continuously keep drawing into the backbuffer canvas and trapped the main canvas into a requestAnimationFrame call you might unnecessarily(or not, that depends on you) lose some frames generating waste of CPU usage and low quality animations.

To help choose the better approach always do your own performance tests for your specific use cases.

And requestAnimationFrame is no needed at all. You are always able to use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` but the pros of using requestAnimationFrame are way bigger than his cons what make it the better approach for animations.

Comment: thanks. Your answer is in parts specific to animations and getting high fps. There is not much being animated in my application, therefore the backbuffer solution works actually better. I will try not adding the canvas to the DOM.

Comment: @wirrbel: I see. If you are rendering graphics on the fly the performance will be better with a back buffer, that's true. So there's no reason to use requestAnimationFrame in this case since you don't need the rendering to be sincronized with the monitor's refresh rate. Use the requestAnimationFrame only when you perform animations in the main canvas.